# Writing post on fresh and clean theme from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to post some post in a fresh and clean theme from WP as at the template shows with an image on the left side, after clicking you can see the image in other place...but I don't achieve it. I have the image,the text but nothing. The url from the blog is blog.axpertia.es, how can I do it?.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: if you want to posts wp post from front end try wordpress function [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) . secondly  what do you mean by after clicking the images should be on right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your style.css file, look for:

```
#post-thumbnail img {
```

and change the `float: right;` to `float: left;`